# Firebase Tutorial fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I was following the Swift Firebase tutorial at https://www.raywenderlich.com/109706/firebase-tutorial-getting-started and ran into a few problems.

When I try to run I get "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value.

I'm sorry for posting pictures instead of code but didn't know where to start and didn't want to copy/paste entire project.

Here is the complete project posted on GitHub:  https://github.com/kjg531/parasnews

[image: stacktrace]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please update your post with a textual snippet of the code, around the line that's crashing and also a textual version of your Firebase data? That will save us a lot of time since we won't have to re-type. This crash could be caused by your structure as well as other things but without seeing the structure it's hard to say.

Comment: Taking a look at the *name* variable is a good place to start. Keep in mind that if an implicitly unwrapped optional is nil and you try to access its wrapped value will trigger a runtime error. Because I can't copy/paste from your question i'll just do this as a comment: I would suggest commenting out all of the variable assignments in the init(snapshot... method and replace it with a print("\\(snapshot.value)") to find out if the snapshot (and name) is valid.

Answer (score 1):

You should write the code like this :

```
name = snapshot.value!["name"] as? String
addedByUser = snapshot.value!["addedByUser"] as? String
completed = snapshot.value!["completed"] as? Bool
```

Change the snapshot.value["blabla"] to this snapshot.value!["blabla"].
It should work n

Answer (score 0):

I think "name" key is not exist or not added on firebase so write your code like this

```
init(snapshot: FDataSnapshot) {
    key = snapshot.key
    name = snapshot.value["name"] as? String
    addedByUser = snapshot.value["addedByUser"] as? String
    completed = snapshot.value["completed"] as? Bool
    ref = snapshot.ref
  }
```

If "name" key is not exist, It will automatic set nil value to name in model class.

Comment: I tried this as well. Crashes as soon as it hits viewDidAppear()